# How to set precedence in OrderBy angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:'-type'">
    <p>{{user.name}}</p>
    <p>{{user.type}}</p>
</div>
```

I have type : 12, 5, 3

I want to give higher precedence to 12 then 3 move 5 to end of line

Comment: Since there is no fixed logic of such sorting, there is no ready-made recipe. You need to sort the collection yourself before repeating on it.

Comment: custom filter ...?

Comment: What is the logic behind 12, 3, 5? Is it alphabetically rather than numerically? Question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this hope this will help you

You need to add group filter

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in countries | orderBy: 'status' | groupBy: 'status'">

  Status : {{ key }}

  <li ng-repeat="player in value">
    player: {{ player.name }} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

See below jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/cojtn8vm/6/

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the collection yourself before repeating it or you need to convert user.type to string and then you can use like given below link

[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/kinjalpgor/cojtn8vm`enter code here`

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cojtn8vm/5/

Birgit should be in second place

Also want to seperate the status into line

i.e Done header should be done value, pending should have pending value please guide

Comment: i am not getting your question @ Justin, as on which criteria you want Birgit in second place? can you plz elaborate?